# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#39;order

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, controller, mybatis

What is causing this exception, I have used the similar approach in a `UserController` and that worked fine. Is the mapping of SQL table with Entity Classes wrong ?

I can't store data and I can't retrieve anything from it either. It keeps giving me the same error, Initially I though my Latitude and Longitude might be wrong but then I tried inserting a simple `user_id` and is being rejected too.

Controller

```
    @Autowired
    OrderMapper orderMapper; 
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public Order PlaceOrder() 
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setUserId(1);
        orderMapper.insert(order);
        return order;
    }
```

OrderMapper

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="com.mena.api.entity.Order">
insert into order (order_id, user_id, start_latitude, 
  start_logitude, end_latitude, end_logitude, 
  total_distance, type, cost, 
  create_time, start_address, end_address, 
  user_id2)
values (#{orderId,jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{userId,jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{startLatitude,jdbcType=DECIMAL}, 
  #{startLogitude,jdbcType=DECIMAL}, #{endLatitude,jdbcType=DECIMAL}, #{endLogitude,jdbcType=DECIMAL}, 
  #{totalDistance,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{type,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{cost,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 
  #{createTime,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}, #{startAddress,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{endAddress,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 
  #{userId2,jdbcType=INTEGER})</insert>
```

And SQL Table Info

[image]

Error Log

```html
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#39;order
    where order_id = 1&#39; at line 6
### The error may exist in file [\khadim\khadimApi\khadimApi\target\khadminapi\WEB-INF\classes\mybatis\OrderMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.mena.api.mapper.OrderMapper.selectByPrimaryKey-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select &#39;true&#39; as QUERYID,           order_id, user_id, start_latitude, start_logitude, end_latitude, end_logitude, total_distance,      type, 
cost, create_time, start_address, end_address, user_id2         from order     where order_id = ?
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near &#39;order
    where order_id = 1&#39; at line 6
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#39;order
    where order_id = 1&#39; at line 6
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:75)
    org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:447)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:167)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:82)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.selectByPrimaryKey(Unknown Source)
    com.mena.api.controller.OrderController.PlaceOrder(OrderController.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Avoid using reserved words as table/column identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order is a reserved word in MySql, this is why your `select ... from order` probably fails with that exception. If order really is the table name in your database, you could escape it as follows:

```
select ... from `order` ...
```

Or better yet would be to use a non-reserved table name, like 'orders'.

Comment: Is there a way to know which words i can't use ?

Comment: You could have a look at following MySql reference which lists all keywords and reserved words: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-O